# I want the four different footer on last page, first-page, odd-page, even-page using XSL-FO

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I am making an XSL:FO file which contains four pages where first-page header contains the title of the chapter, and the odd and even pages has the footer of page numbers and last-page contains the footer of small table

Answer (score 0):

Look at `fo:page-sequence-master` (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_page-sequence-master) and particularly at `fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives` (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_repeatable-page-master-alternatives).

You essentially want to set up your alternatives in the sequence 'first', 'last', 'rest'. (You could also set it up to have different page masters for odd and even pages if you wanted.)

See, for example:

- "Switching between right and left page layouts (<fo:page-sequence-master>)" in "Comprehensive XSL-FO Tutorials and Samples Collection" at https://www.antennahouse.com/comprehensive-xsl-fo-tutorials-and-samples-collection/
- [How to place content at the bottom of the last page of my document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31894200/how-to-place-content-at-the-bottom-of-the-last-page-of-my-document)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/28382375/4092205
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/17651048/4092205